# Assign new value to a string index

Tags: c#, arrays, string, data-conversion

I need to convert the characters `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u` in the user input string to the assigned symbols. Below is what I have so far.

**School assignment**

First prompt the user for the encrypted text string. Validate that this is not left blank. Send this text string into a custom method you will create that will decipher it. Once it is deciphered, return this text string to the main where you will output both the encrypted and decrypted strings.

To decipher the text string you must perform the following character replacements:

- `@` = `a`
- `#` = `e`
- `^` = `i`
- `*` = `o`
- `+` = `u`

**My current code**

```
public static string Decipher (string code)
{
    char[] array = code.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
    {
        if (code.Contains("@") && code.Contains("#") && code.Contains("^") &&
            code.Contains("*") && code.Contains("+"))
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can just use String.Replace - you don't need to convert it to a char array, unless you were very concerned about speed.

Comment: we are not allowed to utilize that string method 

Comment: `code` is an array. To access a single elements, use `[]`. Once you have accessed the element (which is a single character), you can compare it to one of the vowels and set it to something else, e.g. `code[i] = somethingElse;`

Comment: You're on the right track: but instead of `code.Contains()` you want to check the `char` at index `i` now, e.g. `if (array[i] == '@') array[i] = 'a';`. And _after_ the loop you use the modified array to create the result string: `string result = new string(array);` and return that result.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371172/incomplete-answers-converge-to-nearly-identical-acceptable-ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you go through this for loop, it will evaluate true if the string contains `@`, `#`, `^`, `*` *and* `+` anywhere in the string. So if your string is missing any of these symbols, your `if` statement will evaluate to `false` and nothing will happen.

Luckily you can simplify this pretty easily. One way you can do this is to convert your `string` to a `char[]` array and break your logic into multiple `if`-`else` statements, or a single [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) statement, for example:

```
public static string Decipher (string code)
{
    char[] codeArray = code.ToCharArray(); // convert your code string to a char[] array

    for (int i = 0; i < codeArray.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (codeArray[i]) // Get the char at position i in the array
        {
            case '@': // if the character at i is '@'
                codeArray[i] = 'a'; // Change the character at i to 'a'
                break; // break out of the switch statement - we don't need to evaluate anything else
            case '#': // if the character at i is '#'
                codeArray[i] = 'e'; // Change the character at i to 'e'
                break; // break out of the switch statement - we don't need to evaluate anything else
            // repeat for everything else you need to replace!
        }  
    }
    return new String(codeArray); // Once you're all done, create a string from your deciphered array and return it     
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. You can't modify a string with index access. (i.e. `code[i] = 'a'` is wrong)

Comment: Oh whoops, my bad. I'll fix this now.

Comment: You (and other answers) don't have to convert the code to an array, it creates unnecessary computation. Just have it be `char[] codeArray = new char[code.Length];`, and in the case blocks, use `code[i]`.

Comment: Mind removing the downvote? I don't think blistering performance is really a necessity for a homework assignment (This executes in 0.016 seconds in .NET Fiddle) and [the code now runs as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ae5I7u).

Comment: I have only 1 downvote here and it's not on your question. I'm not recommending the change for optimality, I'm recommending it for the sake of OP not learning to do superfluous things in their code.

Comment: The thing is you say OP `needs` to convert `code` to `char[]`, and that is just false and unnecessary. It is the only thing that prevents me from upvoting this answer.

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371172/incomplete-answers-converge-to-nearly-identical-acceptable-ones)

Comment: @Mat fair cop, I'll reword it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different ways of doing it.  Doing string concatenation in a loop (as shown by @Acex) is generally frowned upon; it spins out a lot of "garbage" and can slow things down.  The `Stringbuilder` class is generally a better option.  My code uses Stringbuilders (well, the same one over and over - I clear it in between).

Here are several ways of doing the same thing:

```
const string encoded = "H#ll*, H*w @r# y*+?";

//good old fashioned C-style/brute force:
var buf = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var c in encoded){
    switch(c){
        case '@':
            buf.Append('a');
            break;
        case '#':
            buf.Append('e');
            break;
        case '^':
            buf.Append('i');
            break;
        case '*':
            buf.Append('o');
            break;
        case '+':
            buf.Append('u');
            break;
        default:
            buf.Append(c);
            break;
    }
}
var result = buf.ToString();

//using a lookup table (easily extensible)
buf.Clear();

var decodeDict = new Dictionary<char, char>{
    {'@', 'a'},
    {'#', 'e'},
    {'^', 'i'},
    {'*', 'o'},
    {'+', 'u'},
};

foreach (var c in encoded){
    if (decodeDict.Keys.Contains(c)){
        buf.Append(decodeDict[c]);
    } else {
        buf.Append(c);
    }
}
result = buf.ToString();

//something completely different
//instead of iterating through the string, iterate through the decoding dictionary
buf.Clear();
var working = new StringBuilder(encoded.Length);
working.Append(encoded);
foreach (var pair in decodeDict){
    working.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
result = working.ToString();
```

In each case, `result` holds, well, the result.  Put a breakpoint right after each result assignment and see what's happened.

I'm not providing a lot of comments, step through the code, look up the classes and figure out what I'm doing (you are the student, after all).

Answer (score 0):

It's really as simple as doing this:

```
public static string Decipher(string code)
{
    var map = new Dictionary<char, char>()
    {
        { '@', 'a' },
        { '#', 'e' },
        { '^', 'i' },
        { '*', 'o' },
        { '+', 'u' },
    };

    char[] array = code.ToCharArray();

    array = array.Select(x => map.ContainsKey(x) ? map[x] : x).ToArray();

    return new string(array);
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
string cipher = "*+tp+t";
string plain = Decipher(cipher);
Console.WriteLine(cipher);
Console.WriteLine(plain);
```

This outputs:

```
*+tp+t
output
```

Comment: For this specific question we have a downvoter. he went for a break, you will get your downvote soon after he came back. Answer looks perfect, but i'm not sure as a student op is able to understand this or not

Comment: This is just a bad answer. Not only you obviously answered with stuff that most likely exceeds OP's capabilities (linq, dictionary), but you gave 0 explanation as to how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of alternative

> And when you will be allowed to use existing methods.

you can write something like this:

```
private Dictionary<char, char> mapping = new Dictionary<char, char>()
{
    { '@', 'a' },
    { '#', 'e' },
    { '^', 'i' },
    { '*', 'o' },
    { '+', 'u' },
};

private string Decrypt(string encryptedString) =>
    string.Concat(encryptedString.Select(s => mapping.ContainsKey(s) ? mapping[s] : s));
```

And usage:

```
string result = Decrypt(encryptedString);
```

References: **[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Aodqw0)**

Comment: more compact code is `s => mapping.TryGetValue(s, out var r) ? r : s`

Comment: `string.Concat(...)` instead of `String.Join("", ...)`

Comment: Probably, both field and method should be `static`

Comment: Well yes, I forgot about `Contact` and its literally 1 symbol compact than my code and if you rename `mapping` to for example `map` mine would be more compact.